# Getting my values from a C pointer array

Tags: c, arrays

Really struggling here and cannot figure out how to get my value's from an array.

I first declare this array which I want to hold a set of numbers. IDK why the size is 64, I simply am frustrated and gave it a size.

```
   char *numberList1[64];
```

I then read in a file using some code I found.

```
  FILE * fp;
   char * line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t read;
   char string[100];
   int counter = 0;

   printf("\n\nEnter name of File 1: ");
   scanf("%s", string);

   fp = fopen(string, "r");
   if (fp == NULL) {
       printf("invalid filename of %s",string);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
   while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
       numberList1[counter] = line;
       counter++;
   }
```

Now if were to say something like `printf("%s",numberList1[counter]);` within the `while`, I would get all my numbers back.

However when I say the following, I only get the last item printed out however times there are numbers. (vectorLength).

```
   int j;
   //vectorLength is the user-entered # of lines/numbers in the file.
   for (j = 0; j < vectorLength; j++) {
       printf("Writing out: %s \n", numberList1[j] );
       //write(pipe1[WRITE], currentNum, bitSize+1);  
   }
```

i.e. If I had numbers, 1, 2, 3, 4
I would get: 4 4 4 4

What am I doing wrong??? I have tried to find guides on understanding pointers and arrays in C but I cannot figure it out...

Comment: Where are you assigning `vectorLength`? What is it's value?

Comment: so sorry! I ask the user for it off the bat, it basically is how many numbers/lines are in the file. Hence, how many values should be in the array

Comment: Any clue as to what I am doing wrong, @BrettWolfington?

Comment: Check how many characters were read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not preparing the parameters sent to [**`getline()`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) properly. According to the documentation:

> If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.

You want a new line buffer for each line, and you at-least-seem to want `getline()` to make that for you, so, after each successful read, and once you save the returned buffer pointer allocated by `getline()` in your array, clear the line pointer back to NULL and the length parameter back to zero:

```
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1 && counter < 64) 
{
   numberList1[counter++] = line;
   line = NULL; // <<==== ADDED
   len = 0;     // <<==== ADDED
}

free(line); // note: this is here because, though getline() failed, the
            // documentation for the api mandates its presence.
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found the root of the problem.

In the code below, you are reading each line into memory at the location pointed to by `line`. You are then storing *the pointer* to the memory into each index in the array. The problem is that you are overwriting the memory at the location pointed to by `line` each time you read in a line. As a result, only the last-read value is stored at that location. Since each index in the array points to the same location, each iteration of the final loop in your code will display the same value.

```
char * line = NULL;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
   numberList1[counter] = line; // You are storing the pointer here, NOT the value
   counter++;
}
```

Instead, allocate memory for the array  (getline  does this automatically) at *each* iteration of the loop and copy *that* pointer into the array.

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    numberList1[counter] = line;
    line = NULL;
    counter++;
}
```

Make sure to free all memory allocated during this process.

Comment: Confused on some things. 1. what are `line` and `len`? I assume one is the number of actual characters in the string per line, but idk the other? 2. in the original code it has `char * line` is that the same as `line = (char *)`? 3. What's with all the `len + 1`'s?

Comment: These are the same variables as in your code. When the `getline` function returns, `line` should contain the maximum size of the string to read. `getline` will return the actual number of bytes read, and if `len` is not large enough to contain the string, `line` will be resized to contain it (assuming sufficient memory is available), and `len` will be updated to the size of memory that was allocated.

Comment: So if I already know the size of each line, in advance from user input, can I just set that up by default? i.e. If I know each line will have a 8-bit number..

Comment: Also, I would recommend doing some research on memory allocation, particularly using `malloc()`. the line `line = (char *)malloc(len + 1)` allocates `len + 1` bytes of memory (sufficient to hold a null-pointer at the end of the string), cast to a character pointer.

Comment: And yes, if each line has an 8-bit number, that would indicate that the line size is 3 characters (0-255) or less (plus a newline, and possibly a carriage return). As a result, to hold the number, plus the newline and carriage return, I would set `len` to 5 if you are on Windows and 4 if you are on Linux (Windows includes a carriage return at the end of each line, while Linux only uses newlines).

Comment: " if each line has an 8-bit number, that would indicate that the line size is 3 characters (0-255) or less" If you assume that the 8-bit number is entered in decimal. Otherwise, you may need up to 8 characters if the 8-bit number is entered in binary.

Comment: starting with `line ==NULL` is OK, the `getline` function allocates memory.